# How to enable backdrop for CSS modal?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Here I have a modal in my react app and its working and if I try to close model with the help of close button it also works but the problem arise when I try to close modal with backdrop here what I simply did is I am executing the same modal close function which I am triggering on close button click and it is also working but is also closes modal whenever I click on the inner modal content which I definitely don't want I want to close it only when I click anywhere except my modal inner content so how can I fix as I tried with the help of z-index but it doesn't work:

React:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import classes from "./Cart.module.css";

const Cart = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
  const closeHandler = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    isOpen && (
      <div className={classes.modal} onClick={closeHandler}>
        <div className={classes.root} onClick={closeHandler}>
          <span className={classes.close}>&times;</span>
          <span>Item: Pizza</span>
          <span>Price: $50</span>
          <span>
            <button>Order</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.root {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 25%;
  height: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: 48%;
  bottom: 29%;
}

.close:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event (e) in your `closeHandler` and check if `className` matches the modal class, only then call `setIsOpen(false)`. Try this:

```
 const closeHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.target.className === classes.modal) {
       setIsOpen(false);
    } 
 };
```